# picasso not loading all images from firebase url in android

Tags: android, firebase, picasso, android-glide

I am trying to load images from firebase storage through url, but all images are not being loaded, some are being loaded and some not I am using below code and Picasso library to load the images

```
Picasso.get().load(post.getPost_user_profile_pic_url())
                    .resize(200, 200)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(postUserImage);
```

When I tried to use Glide library  as below

```
Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(post.getPost_user_profile_pic_url()).into(postUserImage);
```

I got the following

W

> /Glide: Load failed for
>   https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/............
>   with size [120x120]
>       class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
>       There was 1 cause:
>       java.io.FileNotFoundException(https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/....................)
>        call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
>         Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed,
>   class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE

How can I rectify this problem to make sure all teh respective images are loaded from the URL?

Comment: Can you paste the full error you are getting? for better idea

Comment: Keep in mind url should be with HTTPs instead of HTTP

Comment: @RanjeetLuhar I have updated the error with more details and it is HTTPS as you said

Comment: as you can see FileNotFoundException is occuring. So check image url again so as per system file is not there.

Comment: @RanjeetLuhar I have checked the Url and there is file with every url

Comment: If you space and other whitespace characters in file name then try after removing all

Comment: @RanjeetLuhar checked for whitespaces as well, no spaces or whitespaces found

Comment: try with replacing with another dummy url and see if images is showing or not?

Comment: @RanjeetLuhar I tried replacing the url with the urls working, it comes out to be the url issue, what could be that issue with the url loaded from different devices? or is it image type or size issue?

Comment: There are many factors 1. Image Name 2. Extension (.png/.jpg/.webp) 3. Security rules of Firebase Storage which restrict to access it 4. Size (which usual take more time to load but not gives error)

Comment: @RanjeetLuhar it was the issue with the storage security rules, when I allowed without any auth it got resolved, but I need to work on the security rules as well. thanks for the great guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Glide to load the image data from a URL, that URL needs to be publicly readable. Since you want the image data to be protected by Firebase's security rules, the URL you're using is by definitely not public.

To integrate Firebase Storage with Glide, you'll need one of Firebase's API [methods to load the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_files) to a stream, into memory, or a local file. From there you can then pass it to Glide.

I'd highly recommend using the [FirebaseUI library that integrates with Glide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage), either directly in your code, or as an example of how to build such an integration. For the specific code that loads the data from Firebase, see this [method in the code](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/storage/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/storage/images/FirebaseImageLoader.java#L132).